# How can I GET JSON from a localhost's API with Alamofire | Swift

Tags: json, swift, networking, localhost, alamofire

I want to get JSON from localhost, this is my code

```
   Alamofire.request(.GET, "localhost/speex/service.php")
        .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
    }
```

but it sends me this error

```
[Request]: <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7fc53960dda0> { URL: localhost/speex/service.php }
[Response]: nil
[Data]: 0 bytes
[Result]: FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc539567ad0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=localhost/speex/service.php, NSErrorFailingURLKey=localhost/speex/service.php, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}
[Timeline]: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 484405610.886649, "Initial Response Time": 484405612.654189, "Request Completed Time": 484405612.654189, "Serialization Completed Time": 484405612.654278, "Latency": 1.76753997802734 secs, "Request Duration": 1.76753997802734 secs, "Serialization Duration": 8.89897346496582e-05 secs, "Total Duration": 1.76762896776199 secs }
```

PD: When I open the url "localhost/speex/service.php" I can see the JSON code correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Localhost can not be accessed within iOS Simulator or device. You need to setup a local IP Address for your localhost like: http://192.168.1.100 and then use this IP Address in your program.